# mod_rewrite to serve a new version of existing files

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have just made a central dynamic script to replace a messy folder full of static files. However, I would like to preserve the old URL's without having to delete those files. Let me give you an example:

I have the following files:

1. /oldpages/projekt1/index.html
2. /oldpages/projekt2/index.html
3. /oldpages/projekt3/index.html

The actual new urls are:

1. /newscript/script.php?name=projekt1
2. /newscript/script.php?name=projekt2
3. /newscript/script.php?name=projekt3

The rewrite rule is:

```
Options -MultiViews -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^oldpages/([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)/(index.html)?$ /newscript/script.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

However, whenever I try to access http://mydomain.com/oldpages/projekt3/index.html it just keeps giving back the old files. After googling, everyone said that multiviews may be the culprit, but apparently, that's not fixing it.

The rule works if the directory doesn't exist on the server, the following works perfectly:

```
Options -MultiViews -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^newpages/([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)/(index.html)?$ /newscript/script.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And http://mydomain.com/newpages/projekt3/index.html gets the right page.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a `.htaccess` in `/oldpages` has `RewriteEngine On`, that overrides all rules in the `.htaccess` in `/`.

Comment: Glad to help. Have a look at [`RewriteOptions Inherit`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions) if you want to put rules in both files.